# Fancier/better WiFi access point or range extender to overcome interference - how to decide?

Tags: wireless-networking, signal-strength, wireless-extender

I'm using a router+switch+wifi access point (let's call it an AP) at home which does not cover my entire apartment well enough. Some physical information:

- The apartment is contained in a 12.5m x 6m rectangle, i.e. I'm not trying to cover some huge area.
- The AP is in a room that's at one of the corners, and cannot be moved from there for various reasons.
- There's a single contiguous area of poor coverage - the far side of the rectangle from the AP's side.

Like I said, I can't move the AP, but I can get new hardware and I can theoretically replace my AP. It seems to me like I have two options:

- Get a better/fancier/more powerful/more sensitive router+switch+AP
- Get a range extender for the problematic area

My questions:

1. How do I decide between these two options? i.e. what are the criteria (other than, say, price)?
2. Are these really the only two options or could I possibly do something else to improve coverage?

**Note:** If more details are necessary I could provide them, but I don't want to turn this into a "what should I buy" post.

Comment: Depending on how large the area you're trying to cover is, it could be anything from getting a higher AC router and putting it in a centrally high location, unless you're trying to cover a larger area than that can cover, then range extenders are your friend in this situation.

Comment: @Dooley_labs: See edit; I'm not trying to cover some huge area, it's probably some kind of interference.

Answer (score 2):

Criteria:

- Any wifi repeater will halve the available bandwidth, because retransmission of wifi frames also takes up airtime (and it gets worse if there are collisions).
- It's not really obvious which home routers make "better" APs.
- Wifi reception is influenced by many factors.

So: First diagnose the problem. *Why* is there a single bad area of poor coverage? How large is the apartment, how large is the area? Is just distance from the AP causing problems? Or is there metal in walls that prevents transmission? Other possible reasons?

After you found this out, you can think about options: If a wall with metal in it blocks transmission, can you place a wifi repeater somewhere where it has unimpeded line of sight view of both the AP and the area you want to cover? Would putting an Ethernet cable somewhere, say from the primary AP to a second AP, be an option? What about powerline repeaters? Etc.

**Edit**

> How can I tell whether a wall has (a significant amount of) metal in it?

For example, because you already drilled a hole, and found metal struts. Or because behind this wall reception is really bad, while everywhere else it is good. Walking around the apartment with an App that shows signal strength might help to figure it out.

12.5m x 6m isn't particularly large, and normally an AP should cover that easily. If the bad reception is in a single room on the far side, either your AP is exceptionally bad, or there is metal somewhere. Another possibility is interference on the same channel from the outside.

Another way gather information is to borrow another AP from someone else, put this into various places in the apartment and measure, or possibly even disconnect your existing AP and do the same - it will still act as AP, even though it doesn't have internet connection any more.

If you can find a place near a power socket where both the far room and the original AP location have good reception, then I'd probably just put a wifi repeater into that socket, if ethernet cable or powerline is not wanted.

Comment: 1. How can I tell whether a wall has (a significant amount of) metal in it? 2. Do you mean a second AP on another frequency band?

Comment: 3. Added some physical information to the question - this is not a question about huge expanses.

Answer (score 1):

Measure the power of your wifi signal several meters from the AP in a clear line of sight. With a decent AP, you should get at least -45dBm 5-6 meters away from the AP. If you get significantly less (e.g. -60), simply buying a better router is likely to improve your reception a lot. Buying a better antenna for your existing router may also be an option, but don't expect miracles: passive antennas may add about 10dBm tops over a simple piece of wire. Buying an external wifi dongle could also help, assuming you're getting poor reception with a laptop which may have a particularly bad internal antenna. See [this article](https://support.metageek.com/hc/en-us/articles/201955754-Understanding-WiFi-Signal-Strength) for the expected levels of wifi signals.

If your signal strength in a clear line of sight is fine, you'll need to either move your AP or install range extenders to provide coverage in areas where your wifi is poor.

Comment: Measure - with a laptop? With some dedicated device?

Comment: @einpoklum Ideally, with the device you'll be using. In Linux, you can run `watch iwconfig` to see the signal strength in dBm, and I bet there are similar tools for Windows / Android / iOS as well.